# Syncing mongo instance with a remote replica set

Tags: mongodb

Production mongodb replicaset is running on "heroku". Working on a staging setup on AWS for testing purpose. How can I sync my new mongodb instance on AWS with the  heroku mongo replicaset data.

I don't want to add AWS mongo instance to production replicaset as any data write on staging will effect production environment.

Any pointers in this direction is greatly needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to sync your staging database once, you can create dump of production server and restore on staging server.

See documentation of [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#mongodump) and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#mongorestore)

However, if you trying to keep your staging server in sync with production on continues base without being member of replica set, unfortunately, it's not supported yet.

Comment: Do we have a mechanism for continuous sync now?